# Git Flow : Bitbucket - Unable to sync branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I create a pull request to release branch from develop branch I get a message saying **"1 commit behind release"**

On clicking 1 commit behind release error comes as "Unable to sync branch". How can I resolve this?